# Mac OSX - Drag and drop in Swing appl running on applet

Tags: macos, swing, drag-and-drop, applet

I'm having some issues making my swing application to work in Mac OSX. This swing application should run on an applet inside the browser.

**Please note that this problem is exclusive to mac osx and only when the applet run on the browser**

The problem I see is that the drop events are not properly delivered to the components inside the Applet.
The following example contains a label and a input field. If you drag from the label to the input field, the label text should be copy into the input field.

```
package com.example;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class DND extends JApplet {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JTextField txtField;
    JLabel lbl;

    private void doStart() {

        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        txtField = new JTextField(20);

        lbl = new JLabel("Drag this text to the input field");
        lbl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 100));
        lbl.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        lbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        lbl.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("text"));
        MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                JComponent jc = (JComponent) e.getSource();
                TransferHandler th = jc.getTransferHandler();
                th.exportAsDrag(jc, e, TransferHandler.COPY);
            }
        };
        lbl.addMouseListener(ml);

        add(txtField);
        add(lbl);

        setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    doStart();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

With this code you have to generate a .jar file which will be used in the following html so you can run the applet in the browser:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Menu test Applet</title>
</head>
<body>
<applet id="AppletID" height="800" width="600" 
  code="com.example.DND" 
  archive="*jar_file*.jar">
</applet>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you pop the applet out of the browser using cmd+shift everything works as expected.

System specs:
Firefox 16.0.2
Mac OS X 10.7.5
JRE version 1.6.0_37-b06 (with plugin 1.6.0_37 but this problem also happens in 1.6.0_31)

Anyone have any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"Anyone have any idea what am I doing wrong?"*  I suspect this is not about what you are doing wrong, but a bug in the JRE used.  (Just for the record, it works as expected on Windows 7 running a 1.7.0_09 JRE.)

Comment: I've found the same behaviour on OsX 10.9.2 (Mavericks) and Java7.
It seems like drag-and-drop is forbidden into OsX browsers.
It's very sad.